# How to refresh a component from another component in Salesforce LWC?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, salesforce-communities

In Salesforce LWC (Lightning Web Component) -

I have created two different components i.e. ComponentA, which is use for create a new record and ComponentB which is displaying list of added records. Once user clicked submit button from ComponentA then ComponentB should be refresh/reload.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 0):

If the components are related (if one contains the other) you can use events to communicate the child component with the parent component by using the dispatchEvent() method (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.events_create_dispatch).

If the components are not related, then you can use the a **Message Channel** to stablish a communication between them. You would need to:

- Create the Message Channel => https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel_intro
- In ComponentB (the receiver) subscribe to the channel => https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel_subscribe
- In ComponentA (the emitter) publish a message to the channel that the ComponentB will receive => https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.use_message_channel_publish

Hope this is useful.